# Crash loading SKTextureAtlas when using xCode Command Line Tools - better answer?

Tags: xcode5, continuous-integration, ios7.1

My iOS7 project uses `SpriteKit` and multible `SKTextureAtlas`. I am able to build and run it without any issues using `xCode5.1.1`.

Trying to run the .ipa build by our build server, which is using `xCode Command Line Tools`, it crashes on startup when trying to load the first texture atlas:

`Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18de52f50 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19a35c1fc objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18de52e90 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   SpriteKit                       0x190cdc4f8 -[SKTextureAtlas loadTextures] + 2708
4   SpriteKit                       0x190cdd440 +[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:] + 208
.
.`

The directory `myTextures.atlas` is contained within the `.app` contents, as well as the actual `.png` files.

EDIT:

It seems that the `Command Line Tools` ignore the `Enable Texture Atlas Generation` Build Setting.

I could work around the issue by:

- Set Build Setting `Enable Texture Atlas Generation` to NO
- Add the follwing as Build Phrase shell script:

`cd "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"/*.app

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/TextureAtlas myAtlas.atlas`

I consider this as an Apple bug and filed it, but better solutions highly appreciated!